# Making a slideshow program

Tags: java, swing, slideshow, jlabel

I am trying to make a slideshow program. I want the next slide to appear when I click (There are only two slides not, but I will add more once the errors r sorted out).
The code compiles fine. But when i click, nothing happens. 
What could possibly go wrong?

```
package project;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

Frame() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ImageIcon slide = new ImageIcon("E:\\Books\\Computer\\Java\\Introduction to Java Programming\\exercise9e\\image\\slide0.jpg");
    JLabel slidesLabel = new JLabel(slide);
    add(slidesLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    slidesLabel.addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
}

public void nextSlide() {
    ImageIcon slide = new ImageIcon("E:\\Books\\Computer\\Java\\Introduction to Java Programming\\exercise9e\\image\\slide1.jpg");
    JLabel slidesLabel = new JLabel(slide);
    add(slidesLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    System.out.println("x");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        nextSlide();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) - Seriously, this is exactly what this was designed for!

Comment: don't create new lable use existing one `JLabel slidesLabel = new JLabel(slide);`

Comment: Actually, its an assignment. So, doing it with CardLayout (haven't stuided yet) may land me into trouble.

Comment: May get you extra points, because you current approach will land you in hot water...

Comment: can't bear the odds. 
I will, however, try it your way -- Just for practice.

Comment: @FastSnail Can't get you. . .

Comment: @Saud each time you press next your programe create a new jlable with image .that's not good.you should change imageicon in  one lable

Comment: @MadProgrammer is it better to use `cardlayout` over changing imageicon  for this .in this case one jlable is sufficient .

Comment: @FastSnail Ultimately it all comes down to needs.  Is it easier to call `CardLayout#next` filled with a bunch of `JLabel`s or have an array of images which you need to manually manage the current index of...

Comment: @FastSnail Also, with `CardLayout`, you get automatic preferred size which will match the largest "view" in the stack

Comment: @FastSnail
`"each time you press next your programe create a new jLable with image "`
and then the program should display this new JLabel overlapped over the previous. I am still confused..

Comment: @Saud yes i was telling you it's redundant there was no need to create new jlables just change imageicon on jlable .and madprogrammer explained you why it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the "main" problem is `BorderLayout` will only manage a single component within any of the five available locations it manages.

Adding another component into the position tends to cause issues, where the component that was first added won't be displayed, or in your case, will remain and could interfere with the new component

"A" solution would be to re-use the same `JLabel` for each slide, simply supply a new value for the `icon` property (or in this example, the `text` property)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel slidesLabel = new JLabel("Apple");
    public Frame() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(slidesLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        slidesLabel.addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
    }

    public void nextSlide() {
        slidesLabel.setText("Banana");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            nextSlide();
        }
    }

}
```

This approach would allow you to place each `icon` into an `array` and simply have a counter which determines which slide is current, so when you click for the next slide, you simply increment the counter, get the next value from the array and apply it to the label

A better (and more appropriate) solution would be to actually use a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

## With icons...

[image: SlideShow]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel slidesLabel = new JLabel();
    private Icon[] icons;
    private int currentSlide = -1;

    public Frame() {
        try {
            // Personally, I'd use File#listFiles to list all the
            // images in a directory, but that might be consider
            // using our initiative...
            icons = new Icon[]{
                new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("..."))),
                new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("..."))),
                new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("...")))
            };
            slidesLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            slidesLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(slidesLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            slidesLabel.addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
            nextSlide();
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void nextSlide() {
        if (currentSlide < icons.length - 1) {
            currentSlide++;
            slidesLabel.setIcon(icons[currentSlide]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            nextSlide();
        }
    }

}
```

## Why simply adding components to a `BorderLayout` is bad...

[image: BadLayout]

All I did was when `nextSlide` was called, create a new `JLabel` assign it the next `icon` and add it to the `Frame` (which is using a `BorderLayout`) and then re-sized the frame.  Because the labels are transparent, they remain visible...

This is why you shouldn't simply add new components to a `BorderLayout`, but, in your case, simply update the properties of the existing `JLabel` to meet the changing needs.

Comment: Can you replace Banana and Apple with ImageIcons.
I'm still having problems.

Comment: Yes, you can simply use `setIcon` instead of `setText` ... but I didn't have any images on hand ;)

Comment: Boom!!
That worked ... THANKS!!!
But.... what was the problem? I tried changing BorderLayout -  no avail.I don't think it's the borderLayout that was messing

Comment: Suppose I have a JButton added in a JFrame. I create another JButton and add it to the same Frame. The new button replaces the old one. 
In this case, it's the opposite; the new JLabel  is superceded by the old one. Why?

Comment: @Saud just resize your frame you will see expected result .when you add component you have to call revalidate /repaint

Comment: It's not, both buttons are actually there, it's just that the `BorderLayout` now ignores the first and keeps the second up-to-date.  In your case, because the labels are transparent, you have the potential for seeing both labels simultaneously as the stack on top of each other

Comment: @FastSnail Given the fact the the OP is using labels, resizing the frame will only highlight the issue with trying to add new components to a `BorderLayout`, as the first will remain, unchanged, will the second will be updated by the `BorderLayout`, potentially showing both labels stacked ontop of each other (as `JLabel` is transparent by default).  You are correct to encourage the OP not to add new components, but to reuse old ones

Comment: Still getting nowhere. I'll discuss this with my instructor. Dont wanna waste ur time anymore...
Thanks for your help ...
I really appreciate it

Comment: Well, there's now to working examples for you to work from, hopefully one will help you get some ideas ;)

Comment: Going through the second one right now... Hope it gets me somewher

Comment: @MadProgrammer Got it...Thanks ...  Had I asked my instructor this many times, things would have gone disastrous. Thanks for your help.